# Yii2 - yii\base\InvalidRouteException

Tags: php, exception, controller, action, yii2

I'm trying to do an aplication with Yii2 and when I add a new action to the default controller:

```
public function actionMostrarArticle($id)
{

    $article = (new Query)->select('*')->from('subasta_actual')->where('id = :id');
    $article->addParams([':id' => $id]);

    $imatges = obtenir_imatges_active_from_objecteId($id);

    return $this->render('article',['article' => $article, 'imatges' => $imatges]);

}
```

and I ask for it:

```
<a href="<?=Url::toRoute(['site/mostrarArticle', 'id' => $model->id]);?>">Me interesa</a>
```

I have the exception:

`exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request: site/mostrarArticle' inexception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request: site/mostrarArticle'`

Can anyone helps me?

Thanks!

Toni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a url for that route as follows:

```
<?= Url::toRoute(['site/mostrar-article', 'id' => $model->id]) ?>
```

It is explained [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/493#issuecomment-18943020)